# Extended FOSUserBundle Not Creating Base Entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Our project has been migrated from Symfony 2.1 to 2.3 and now to 2.7.  FOSUserBundle created it's own properties on 2.1 but does not on the later editions.

php app/console doctrine:schema:update actually results in commands to drop the existing username, usernameCanonical, etc., fields.

Additionally, when trying to log in using our log in form, we get:

```
"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical at .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:94
```

It appears the system has no knowledge of the FOSUserBundle entities that accompany our extended base user.

I have reduced our extended user class to the default as a test and still get the same issues.  Here is the current code and configuration:

config.yml

```
    orm:
        #default_entity_manager: ~
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
        result_cache_driver:
            type: memcached
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 11211
            instance_class: Memcached
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: memcached
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 11211
            instance_class: Memcached
        query_cache_driver:
            type: memcached
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 11211
            instance_class: Memcached
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true

        mappings:
            FOSUserBundle: ~

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: ODR\OpenRepository\UserBundle\Entity\User
    change_password:
        form:
            type: odr_user_change_password
```

security.yml

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            # Symfony >= 2.8
            # csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # Symfony < 2.8
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        remember_me:
            key:      asdlkjf2ji802fiuaskdjokjhafsdjsfdjhjh
            lifetime: 1209600
            path:     /
            domain:   ~
```

User Class [ src/ODR/OpenRepository/UserBundle/Entity/User.php ]

```
namespace ODR\OpenRepository\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Running:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

does not show the FOS User or Group entities as being mapped.  It does show our user class but the extension does not appear to pull in the base properties.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is usually the case when having upgrade problems, the issue turned out to be an incorrect dependency.

Updating the composer.json to include all the correct dependencies as shown in the reference composer.json:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/composer.json

solved the issue.  Our doctrine version was not correct and was incorrectly identifying the FOSUserBundle parent class as "transient" so that it was not compiled into the metadata array.

After updating the composer.json file and running `composer update` all schemas generated correctly and login functionality was restored.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the fos routing to routing config ?

Comment: Yes - all routing is in the routing config as well.  We don't use the "registration" routing so we explicitly load the other four routes.  Even when loading via the "all.xml" route, the system shows the same issues.